# Disable is not function using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Users are requested to select an option in step 1, then step 2 will appear, otherwise step 2 is disabled. The same goes for step 3 whereby users are requested to select step 2, otherwise step 3 is disabled.

The problem is that a user already selected at step 2 but step 3 is still disabled. The user should be able to select on Step 3.

```js
$(function() {
  //1st Step
  $("#selRegion").change(function() {
    $(".subCat").hide();

    $("#stateplaceholder").hide();
    
    //2nd Step
    if ($("#selRegion").val() == "") {
      $("#stateplaceholder").show();

      //3rd step
      if ($("#selAllRegions").val() != "" || $("#selCentral").val() != "") {
        $("#datefrom").removeAttr("disabled");
        $("#dateto").removeAttr("disabled");
        $("#time").removeAttr("disabled");
      }
    }

    var val = $(this).val();
    if (val == "all") {
      $("#selAllRegions").show();
    } else if (val == "central") {
      $("#selCentral").show();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.subCat {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="myform" id="myform" action="">
  <div>
    <div>
      <p>STEP 1 : Choose Region</p>
      <select id="selRegion">
        <option value="">..Select..</option>
        <option value="all" id="AllRegions">All Regions</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>STEP 2 : Choose State</p>
    <select id="stateplaceholder" onchange="getAllRegions(this)" disabled>
      <option value="">Please select Region first</option>
    </select>
    <select id="selAllRegions" onchange="getAllRegions(this)" class="subCat">
      <option value="">..Select..</option>
      <option value="abc">ABC</option>
    </select>
    <select id="selCentral" onchange="getCentral(this)" class="subCat">
      <option value="">..Select..</option>
      <option value="xyz">XYZ</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <p>STEP 3 : Choose Date and Time</p>
    <p>Please choose Date FROM.</p>
    <input id="datefrom" class="date-picker" placeholder="Date From" type="text" disabled>
    <p>Please choose Date TO.</p>
    <input id="dateto" class="date-picker" placeholder="Date To" type="text" disabled>
    <p>Please choose TIME Interval.</p>
    <input id="time" class="time-picker" placeholder="Time by Hourly" type="text" disabled>
    <button id="btnSubmit" type="button">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mastersuse/0c84rk9v/28/)

Comment: You havent included jQuery in your fiddle

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen it looks like it's bellow the HTML and the question hasn't been edited. What specifically is missing?

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith the JQuery library, not the Javascript code. It has been edited to include that now.

Comment: I've updated to a runnable snippet and added jQuery but there is still code missing: `"ReferenceError: getAllRegions is not defined"`

Comment: What does the title of the question have to do with this code? `.disable()` is not called anywhere within this coce.

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith the jQuery *library* is missing from the JS fiddle, so it doesn't even work. I've converted the code here into a runnable snippet *and* included jQuery but it wasn't here originally even before I did that.

Comment: @VLAZ it was working for me.

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith open the console: `ReferenceError: $ is not defined`

Answer (score 2):

I have modified the jquery snippet to make it work.
I have added a change() method to Step 2 selector.

```
$(function() {
    //1st Step
    $("#selRegion").change(function() {

    $(".subCat").hide();

    $("#stateplaceholder").hide();
    //2nd Step
    if ($("#selRegion").val() == "") {
      $("#stateplaceholder").show();    

      //3rd step
      if ($("#selAllRegions").val() != "" || $("#selCentral").val() != "") {

        $("#datefrom").removeAttr("disabled");
        $("#dateto").removeAttr("disabled");
        $("#time").removeAttr("disabled");

      }     

    } 

    var val = $(this).val();
    if (val == "all") {
      $("#selAllRegions").show();
    } else if(val == "central") {
      $("#selCentral").show();
    } 
  });
  $("#selAllRegions").change(function(){
        if ($("#selAllRegions").val() != "" || $("#selCentral").val() != "") {

        $("#datefrom").removeAttr("disabled");
        $("#dateto").removeAttr("disabled");
        $("#time").removeAttr("disabled");

      } 
  })
});
```

Comment: I have applied your code but not change. step 3 still disable.

Comment: @mastersuse its working here in this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/subbukarbyl/pbjftyzh/1/